# Redirect a url to another url

Tags: linux, hosts

I need to redirect a url to another url. THe PC where this should be done has Linux but no server program such as Apache. When the user type www.mycomerp.com, it should redirect it to http://localhost:8069/. The http://localhost:8069/ runs on a remote server and between the user pc and the remote server there is a tunnel. I though this can be done in /etc/host.conf, can you help??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. `/etc/hosts` can only be used to map hostnames to IP addresses; you will need to set up a web server that performs the redirect to the port.